# Mat Table -How to select only one mat radio button in column of radio buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material, ionic4, angular8, mat-table

How to set mat radio button when we make a primary that contact detail then save it shown on (image 1)
[image: image1]

Shown (image 2) when we get detail on the click of Save button

[image: image2]

then shown on mat table (image 3)
I want set selected only one radio button on getting the primary true before image shown

[image: image3]

there is a code for Mat radio button on the mat table

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="primary" sticky>
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Primary </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;">
                  <mat-radio-group> 
                    <mat-radio-button></mat-radio-button>
                  </mat-radio-group>
                </td>
              </ng-container>
```

Comment: its unclear what you want to achieve....you want only one radio button among group of radio buttons to be set when user selects as primary?

Comment: yes I want to Selected radio button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle click of each radio button to get the selected radio button. To make only one checked in column of radio buttons  check whether current element's id is equal to selected one's id
`[checked]="primaryContact.id == element.id"`

Modify your radio button template to template below

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="primary" >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Primary </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;">
                <mat-radio-button (click)="primaryClick(element)"
               [checked]="primaryContact.id == element.id" ></mat-radio-button>
            </td>
   </ng-container>
```

and in ts create instance variable to hold the current contact which is selected as primary. To avoid errors set its value to first row of data.

```
 primaryContact={primary:false,name:'snfjn',mobile:328754,email:'@fndn',...your fields};
```

and now handler function for setting the primaryContact to selected radiobutton's element

```
  primaryClick(element){
        this.primaryContact=element;
        console.log(this.primaryContact.name)
      }
```

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-demo-wjpqsy